# Is there an easy way to understand the difference between AWS Elasticache and RDS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-elasticache

I'm learning AWS, kind of confusing about [Elasticache & RDS](https://stackshare.io/stackups/amazon-elasticache-vs-amazon-rds-for-mysql), I read the article in this link, but still confused, can someone explain a little bit? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a general question about storage technologies: "how does a cache differ from a database?"

A cache is not (typically) a persistent data store. Its data is ephemeral. The purpose of the cache is to increase the perceived performance of an actual database, sitting behind the cache. The database stores the actual data persistently, and is the authoritative source of data. The cache sits in front of the database and tries to improve the performance of your application by detecting queries that it already knows the answer to and serving up cached results directly to your application, to save having to go to the database.

Of course, the cache will get out of date over time and so you need a process for expiring data from the cache when it becomes inaccurate, thus causing the next query for that piece of data to go to the actual database, and that new data can be cached until it expires.

Answer (score 1):

RDS stands for **relational database service**. If you need managed instances of relational databases like Oracle, MS-SQL server, MySQL, MariaDB, or PostgreSQL then you need to use RDS.

Elasticache however is **caching db as a service**. It supports two popular engines memcache and redis.

DynamoDB is **no-sql DB as a service**.

Answer (score 1):

Use cases for RDS and elasticache are very different.

**Use RDS When,**

there is a need to persist data

needs ACID compliance

require oltp db engine

**Use in-memory distributed cache such as elasticache when,**

reduce latency

Offload db pressure

handle transient data